# How to configure Angular.js to user default host?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-http

For example, I have this call:

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: '/someUrl'}).
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  // this callback will be called asynchronously
  // when the response is available
}).
error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  // called asynchronously if an error occurs
  // or server returns response with an error status.
});
```

I need it to request http://my-api-url.com/someUrl, but I don't want to type it everywhere because it will change in the future.

How can I configure it globally ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a constant:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.constant('myUrls', {
    someUrl: 'http://my-api-url.com/someUrl,',
});

mayApp.directive('myDirective', ['myUrls', function (myUrls) {
    return {
        ....
        // use myUrls.someUrl
        ....
    };
}]);
```

[AngularJS Module](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module)

Answer (score 0):

i don't think you can, that would cripple any other call to other url so what you could do is setting a host variable in a service pointing to the host you want and then in every call set your url as.

```
$http.get(service.host+'/somePath'}).
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

}).
error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

});
```